# Can we replace the kernel config file and get the desired changes in the kernel?

Tags: kernel, configuration, compiling

The question heading is bit confusing I will try to explain myself.

I have downloaded kernel source code (3.2.29)

I have a kernel config file from another system (with the same hardware), what I want to do is to able to replace my kernel config file with this kernel config file which has all the desired changes I want in the kernel and compile and install the new kernel.

So is it even possible to do so? As far as I think it should be possible because ultimately the config utilities edit this file only.

If it is possible then can someone can guide me as in how to proceed with this correctly.

I am new to kernel hacking but love learning it.

Comment: should i port it to SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. What you need to do is to copy the configuration file to `.config` in the root of the source tree and then run `make oldconfig` so that it can prompt you for options that have been added to the new version.